# Usage of Jibx2WSDL to generate wsdl from java

Tags: web-services, cxf, apache-axis, wsdl2java, jibx

I'm using `jibx2wsdl` plugin to convert `wsdl` from `java`.

But for java collection list, i am getting same name for all the lists.

Everytime i generate `jibx` i manually rename the lists.

Is there a solution for it.

Also let me know if this prob is not there with some other libraries(cxf,xmlbeans,watever..).

Here is one sample i attached of my wsdl for java list.

```
<collection field="reportingYearList" usage="optional" create-type="java.util.ArrayList">

<value name="**string**" type="java.lang.String">

<collection>
```